# SQL User Defined Function Within Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, user-defined-functions

I have a user defined function in SQL called getBuisnessDays it takes @startdate and @enddate and returns the number of business days between the two dates. How can I call that function within my select?

Here's what I'd like to do..

```
SELECT getBusinessDays(a.opendate,a.closedate) 
FROM account a
WHERE ...
```

Comment: Just remember that UDFs can often kill query performance depending on how the optimizer reacts to them. They often mean processing row by row rather than set-based. For your situation you might be better off using a calendar table and selecting against that when needed.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Yes, you can do almost that:

```
SELECT dbo.GetBusinessDays(a.opendate,a.closedate) as BusinessDays
FROM account a
WHERE...
```

Comment: damn - beat me to it - you need the owner prefix

Answer (score 15):

If it's a table-value function (returns a table set)
you simply join it as a Table

this function generates one column table with all the values from passed comma-separated list

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.udf_generate_inlist_to_table('1,2,3,4')
```

Answer (score 8):

Use a scalar-valued UDF, not a table-value one, then you can use it in a SELECT as you want.