# Calling a User-defined Scalar function within an Execute Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cast integer and concatenate to varchar in TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936180/cast-integer-and-concatenate-to-varchar-in-tsql)

I have created two scalar functions that each return `uniqueidentifer` types. I need to call these procedures in an execute statement but I seem to have syntax wrong.

```
Exec spModifyProductPropertyValue 
     @PAVID, 
     fnGetPropertyIDbyLabel(@Label7, @USPID, 0, 1), 
     @ProductID, 
     @Value7, 
     fnGetPINID(@7PIN), 
     0, 
     @counter out
```

What I notice is that when I call the function separately and then pass use the output from theprevious call in the call above, like so

```
Declare
      @PropertyID as uniqueidentifier = null

Select @PropertyID = fnGetPropertyIDbyLabel(@Label7, @USPID, 0, 1)

Exec spModifyProductPropertyValue 
         @PAVID, 
         @PropertyID, 
         @ProductID, 
         @Value7, 
         fnGetPINID(@7PIN), 
         0, 
         @counter out
```

The compiler does not complain much. Problem with this approach is that I end up creating so many of these temp variables(almost 50), something I want to try to avoid. I would appreciate any help in getting this correct please.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967035/using-function-as-a-parameter-when-executing-a-stored-procedure. It's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for `UDF` is

```
expression... function_name(value_1, value_2, ... value_n)...
```

So, you can only pass values, NOT expressions.

since using the function is an expression, 
inside the calling of another function

```
     Exec spModifyProductPropertyValue 
     @PAVID, 
     dbo.fnGetPropertyIDbyLabel(@Label7, @USPID, 0, 1) as GetPropertyID,  --Expression
     (..)
```

is not possible.

So, yes, you will have to create variables. But if all are int, maybe you could create one and using it in each use of function.
Or modify your function to do in only one that thing that two functions do.

Answer (score -1):

You need the owner prefix:

```
Exec spModifyProductPropertyValue 
     @PAVID, 
     dbo.fnGetPropertyIDbyLabel(@Label7, @USPID, 0, 1) as GetPropertyID, 
     @ProductID, 
     @Value7, 
     dbo.fnGetPINID(@7PIN) as GetPINID, 
     0, 
     @counter out
```

Awnser was here: [SQL User Defined Function Within Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363838/sql-user-defined-function-within-select)

Comment: That results in an incorrect syntax error still.