# Nested user-defined functions in tsql. Parameters passing trough INSERT-SELECT structures

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, parameter-passing, user-defined-functions

I have got two SQLServer2008 user-defined functions: fn_Top and fn_Nested. 
The first one, fn_Top, is structured in this way:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Top]
      RETURNS @Results table (
                        MyField1 nvarchar(2000),
                        MyField2 nvarchar(2000)
                       )
        AS    
        BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO 
                    @Results 
                    (
                    MyField1,
                    MyField2 
                    )
                    SELECT 
                        item,  
                        (SELECT MyString FROM dbo.fn_Nested(x.MyCounter))
                    FROM 
                    OtherTable x
       RETURN      
       END
```

I would like to perform a sort of dynamic parameter passing to the second function, fn_Nested, reading the values of the numeric field MyCounter in the table OtherTable.

Fact is, x.MyCounter is not recognized as a valid value. 
Everething works fine, on the other hand, if I set in fn_Nested a static parameter, IE dbo.fn_Nested(17).

Is there anyone who can suggest a workaround to solve this problem ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does dbo.fn_Nested() return?

Comment: Or, to be more clear, is dbo.fn_Nested a scalar or table-valued function?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `fn_Nested` is a table-valued function, your syntax is fine (although it could be simplified).
The error would seem to indicate that either `OtherTable` does not have a column named `MyCounter`, or that it is not a column type that can be implicitly converted into numeric value.
What is the exact error?

On a side note, you could simplify `fn_Top` by writing it as an inline table-valued function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_Top()
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
(  
        SELECT x,item as MyField1, y.MyString AS MyField2
          FROM dbo.OtherTable x
   CROSS APPLY dbo.fn_Nested(x.MyCounter) AS y
)
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax using the second function is described here

[SQL User Defined Function Within Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363838/sql-user-defined-function-within-select)

```
create table OtherTable (
item varchar(10),
MyCounter int
);

CREATE FUNCTION fn_Nested(@Id int)
RETURNS varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
   RETURN 'testString ' + CAST(@Id AS VARCHAR(3))
END;

INSERT INTO OtherTable SELECT 'item1', 1
INSERT INTO OtherTable SELECT 'item2', 2

SELECT item,
dbo.fn_Nested(x.MyCounter) as MyString
FROM OtherTable x
```

Results:

item1   testString 1

item2   testString 2